# style only content area of a div with padding

Tags: html, css

I want to style only *the content* area of a div *having a padding* to visualize its content boundary like the inner box in the dev-tools is colored by the web browser. I've tried many things but either the css recommendations are not yet implemented like or maybe I use it in the wrong way.

```
<div class="around">
  <div class="div-with-padding outline-content">
    stuff ...
  </div>
</div>

.around { margin: 50px auto; width: 400px; padding: 0px; }
.div-with-padding { min-height: 200px; padding: 15px; }
```

I've added an outline to the div just for comparison. The `position: relative` below is needed because its child's max-height/width only fits to the matched div if its position is relative.

```
.outline-content {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  position: relative; /* in the original post I've used bootstrap instead */
}
```

I've found no way to do this within the original div so I've added a pseudo-element.

First try:

```
.outline-content::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: max-content; height: max-content;
  outline: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

I don't really understand how max-content works. I've tried also others [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#Syntax). Maybe it doesn't work because I've set `position: absolute;` to don't change the page itself.

Second try:

```
.outline-content::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 30px); height: calc(100% - 30px);
  outline: 1px dotted blue;
}
```

The question is how to get parent's padding = `30px` if it isn't always the same. I've tried much more but without success.

I know with jQuery this problem becomes easy. If anybody knows an answer using only css … I really like to know it. Please also correct mistakes in my code snippets (`width: max-content;` and the like).

Thanks!

(this post includes some adaptions to the comments)

Comment: Can you show us your html code?

Comment: @Filipe Ferreira: First snippet in the question. It isn't highlighted correctly though due to all the ... surrounding it.

Comment: @BoltClock just that? can you edit and show all the code inside of the div?

Comment: I'm not the OP, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't matter what's *inside* this element.

Comment: I think this doesn't matter. I've removed everything that isn't part of my question to keep it as short as possible. In the original I use the outline-content class as placeholder with height: 200px but it should not has any effect to the question.

Comment: Have you tried adding an additional inner div with widht and height set to 100%, and applying your styles to that div?

Comment: An addidtional inner div:  `.outline-content>div {width: 100%; height:100%; position:relative;}` and `.outline-content>div::before { … }` works well if the parent's height and width are fixed but mostly the height isn't … I had the same idea as well but I haven't tried it because it needs further manipulation of my html.

Answer (score 1):

The magic css-property is called "**background-clip**".

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    outer-content
    <div class="inner">
        inner-content
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}

.inner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-clip: content-box;
    -moz-background-clip: content-box;
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/u2vyqdc6/2/

As you can see:

One surrounding div with some content and some padding so you can see better what's going on.
Inside is another div with content, padding and "background-clip: content-box".

"background-clip" works just like "(-moz-)border-box". It tells the browser how to handle the background-specific box-model.

And the best thing?
Browser-support is almost universal at 95%: 
http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

Comment: Works great for background-colors but does not work for outline, box-shadow and other stylings. Thanks anyway!

Comment: That's pretty much how it should work... Since it's only a background-clipping... outline is "another border" so clearly outside of the padding, box-shadow the same since it applies to the outside of the box-model.

So... basically your only choice - if you want to use those other css-props - is to use another wrapper in your HTML or maybe some things can be done with :before and :after pseudo-elements in your CSS.

Comment: With css pseudo elements and the experimental keyword-values of width on mdn (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) – of course these values are only supported by moz but this may be a solution in the future.